# How to add and Train a model and then add it to the flutter google ml kit

Tags: flutter

how to create a customized model and train it, then add this model to my flutter app ?

Any expertise with flutter goole ml kit can help with that?

Comment: An ML model is a function after all when you extract it, as far as I know. You can just implement function to take input from the app and return result. May you can create a server side method. And also have you tried FireBase ML.